# How do I properly get the date and time?

Tags: date, reactjs

I am new to react and trying to get the actual date and time but I can't figure out how to do so :(

Could someone help me please !

I try to get the date in the initial state and actualise it every second. When I run it, I get a white screen.

```
import React from 'react';
import './Menubar.css';
import Time from 'react-time';

const Menubar = React.createClass({
getInitialState() {
    return {
        now: new Date().now(),
    };
},

getRealTime: function() {
    this.setState(
        {
            now: new Date().now(),
        })
},

/**
 * Render the Menubar component
 * @return {Component} the App Component rendered
 */
render() {
    setInterval(this.getRealTime(), 1000);
    return (
        <div className="Menubar">
            <ul className="Menubar-menu">
                <div className="">
                    <li className="Menubar-name">login name</li>
                    <li className="Menubar-date"><Time value={this.state.now} format="DD/MM/YYYY" /></li>
                    <li className="Menubar-time"><Time value={this.state.now} format="HH:mm:ss" /></li>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
});

export default Menubar;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two things:

1. `new Date().now()` is not a function, `new Date()` returns the current date and time, so no need to add it.
2. You try to set the state inside the render function (calling `getRealTime` every single render, which causes a re-render). As I understand, you want to update the time every second. You could set that up in `componentDidMount`.

Here's your Menubar component with those things fixed. I also clear the interval when the component unmounts:

```jsx
const Menubar = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      now: new Date(),
    };
    this.interval = null;
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    const self = this;
    self.interval = setInterval(function() {
      self.setState({
        now: new Date(),
      });
    }, 1000);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Menubar">
        <ul className="Menubar-menu">
          <div className="">
            <li className="Menubar-name">login name</li>
            <li className="Menubar-date"><Time value={this.state.now} format="DD/MM/YYYY" /></li>
            <li className="Menubar-time"><Time value={this.state.now} format="HH:mm:ss" /></li>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! Have been looking for this for more than two hours :)

Answer (score 0):

To just get the current date you can use

```
var dateVariable = new Date()
dateVariable.getDate()
```

OR if you want the current Date & Time in full form then,

```
var dateVariable = Date().toLocaleString()
```

You can find a comprehensive list of methods available on:
https://hdtuto.com/article/react-js-get-current-date-and-time-example

The above link saved a lot of my time. Hope it works. Happy hacking!

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add to IronmanX46's answer, but it won't let me comment.

I wanted to point out that you can do the exact same thing as

```
var dateVariable = new Date()
dateVariable.getDate()
var dateVariable = Date().toLocaleString()
```

by simply doing

```
var dateVariable = Date()
```

As per the documentation:

> Date()
> When called as a function, returns a string representation of the
> current date and time. All arguments are ignored. The result is the
> same as executing new Date().toString().

There are lots of good websites out there that will give you examples of how to do things, but I find it saves time to just go read the documentation, which usually includes examples. I'll then go check out other examples if I can't understand the documentation.

[Date Documentation Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32179664)